# MYSQL: UNDECLARED VARIABLE NEW

Tags: mysql, database, variables, triggers

is there anything wrong with my code? i really think it's alright, the error is "undeclared variable NEW". once again i'm converting from oracle to MySQL in this project so i need a few help on the language and syntax

```
CREATE TRIGGER `customer_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `customer` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SELECT CONCAT('C', SUBSTR(NEW.NAME,1,1),SUBSTR(NEW.NAME,INSTR(NEW.NAME,' ')+1,1),
                                   LPAD(COALESCE(MAX
                                                (SUBSTR(CUSTOMER_ID, 5, 5))+1, 1
                                                ), 5, 0))
  FROM CUSTOMER 
  INTO NEW.CUSTOMER_ID
  where NEW.CUSTOMER_ID LIKE CONCAT('C', SUBSTR(NEW.NAME,1,1),
  SUBSTR(NEW.NAME,INSTR(NEW.NAME,' ')+1,1), '%');
END
```

If name : Robert William
then the code should be "CRW00001"

Comment: the error is in `into new.customer_id` . you are trying to put the result of select statement in new.customer_id, where new is undefined

Comment: @Sachin : new.customer_id is i'm changing the new.customer_id before it is inserted into the database. mysql allowed that kind of syntax inside trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to edit and edit my code through internet and i found the answer

New. can't be used inside select and somehow  `INTO`  is giving me error if it is placed after `FROM`, so instead i placed it before and here's the code that worked in mysql

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `customer_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `customer` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE TEMPKODE VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE TEMP VARCHAR(5);
SET TEMP:= CONCAT('C', SUBSTR(NEW.NAME,1,1),SUBSTR(NEW.NAME,INSTR(NEW.NAME,' ')+1,1));
SELECT CONCAT(TEMP,LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(SUBSTR(CUSTOMER_ID, 5, 5))+1, 1
                                                ), 5, 0))
INTO TEMPKODE
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID LIKE CONCAT(TEMP,'%');
 SET NEW.CUSTOMER_ID := TEMPKODE;
END
```

Answer (score 2):

> [13.2.9.1 SELECT ... INTO
>   Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)
>
> ...
>
> The INTO clause can name a list of one or more variables, which can be
>   user-defined variables, stored procedure or function parameters, or
>   stored program local variables. ...
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `customer_before_insert`;

DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER `customer_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `customer`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    /*
    DECLARE TEMPKODE VARCHAR(10);
    DECLARE TEMP VARCHAR(5);
    SET TEMP := CONCAT('C', SUBSTR(NEW.NAME, 1, 1), SUBSTR(NEW.NAME, INSTR(NEW.NAME, ' ') + 1, 1));
    */
    DECLARE TEMP VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT CONCAT('C', SUBSTR(NEW.NAME, 1, 1), SUBSTR(NEW.NAME, INSTR(NEW.NAME, ' ') + 1, 1));

    /*
    SELECT CONCAT(TEMP, LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(SUBSTR(CUSTOMER_ID, 5, 5)) + 1, 1), 5, 0)) INTO TEMPKODE
    FROM CUSTOMER 
    WHERE CUSTOMER_ID LIKE CONCAT(TEMP,'%');

    SET NEW.CUSTOMER_ID := TEMPKODE;
    */
    SET NEW.CUSTOMER_ID := (
                            SELECT CONCAT(TEMP, LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(SUBSTR(CUSTOMER_ID, 5, 5)) + 1, 1), 5, 0))
                            FROM CUSTOMER
                            WHERE CUSTOMER_ID LIKE CONCAT(TEMP, '%')
                           );
END|

DELIMITER ;
```